# Help Needed : Render As PDF Size Exceeding 30 MB

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

My Visual Force Page is not loading because the size of the PDF is exceeding 30 MB.I am showing multiple images on the PDF which are stored in attachments.
Each attachment(Image)  size is more than 1MB to 3MB
Can you suggest any way to overcome this issue while uploading attachment we can reduce the size to less than 500KB through apex?

**NOTE**

1.I suggested my business not to upload attachments more than 1 MB by displaying a javascript alert.But the business wants this funtionality it should work for more than 30MB.

2.I have contacted salesforce if there is any possibilty to increase the limitation more than 30 MB.They have said No its not possible.

Comment: The 30MB limit is non-negotiable. You can reduce the image sizes by resizing the resolution of the images down to a manageable size, say at most 2000x2000, which is fine for most PDF purposes. You'll want to use HTML5 Canvas elements in Visualforce, or use an external system like Heroku to resize the images. Apex Code is not well-suited for resizing images, because there's no inherent ability to modify data at the byte level.

Comment: @sfdcfox. Thanks for the reply.Can you guide me if any docs are there how to use HTML 5 Canvas Elements in Visual Force or any docs how to use external system like heroku to resize images.

Comment: I can try to write up an example, but basically, you create a canvas, set the width and height, draw the image, then extract it via getDataURL, and finally save it back to the server.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to avoid this limitation in SF... You can check third party tools for generating reports with connector to SF , they probably won't have such limitation, but they are not free.   If you keep working on SF, you will either need to reduce the images size, or possible you can split the PDF (if the PDF shows list of records, then in your process, you can limit the user to choose upto X records in single PDF), or you can also generate more than 1 PDF in single process.